# How do you edit an MVC 5 form so that it adds a combination of user inputted data and dynamic data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm creating a website where the user can make and share lists of their favourite things. I've included the authentication feature and added my extra database features into it. I've auto generated the controller and views from the models imported from the database. When the user creates a list, rather than selecting which user they are from a dropdown, I want their username to be automatically set as the author of that entry in the database. The username doesn't even need to be visible in the form. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried editing the ActionResult Create() control so that it uses the User.Identity.GetUsername() to find the current username. However, it places it into a dropdown one letter at a time. I don't really want it to appear on the page in any way...

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        string author = User.Identity.GetUserName();
        ViewBag.author_id = author;

    }
```

Ideally the user just adds the title of the list i.e. "My Favourite Arnie Films". On the database table for the list, it will then have their username and the list title.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do without posting any of your CRUD actions

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply Sean, is the ActionResult Create() not a CRUD action?

Comment: Why are you adding the author to the `ViewBag` if you don't want to use it in the view?

Comment: You need to get the `author` in the `POST` method of the `Create` action. There you can use it without letting the `UI` know about it. Makes sense?

Comment: @user8639588 It should be yes but currently it takes no object from your view, so it's not clear what it is you want to create. I imagine you have a note object you need to pass into that method?

Comment: thank you all, and I appreciate it's not 100% clear with the limited code I have shown. yes that makes sense Gonzalo. I will try removing anything from Viewbag that I don't need to show and then play with editing the POST section. will let you know how it pans out (p.s. there's obviously more than one variable in the create actionResult in the actual project). Much appreciated! ps. not familiar of the terminology- 'note object'